Outlook Python Azure/MSgraph API get access token error possible admin problem using work account login for link
Hello i am following a tutorial on outlook python api automation and which the original code works using authority='https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/' but our situation is my mom is the boss of the company i work for (so i also have full access on her behalf for her logins along with mine) and her account must be the main overall admin user and underneath if i understand correctly is me and the other employees correct me if i'm wrong and i believe it's a work account, i also believe using the tenant id (actual id in replace of tenantid) like authority='https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}/' worked at first but then kept giving the error
PS C:\Users\Nicolas\tutorial-outlook-api-crash-course> & c:/Users/Nicolas/tutorial-outlook-api-crash-course/Scripts/python.exe "c:/Users/Nicolas/tutorial-outlook-api-crash-course/ms_graph ((3 gpt))original - Copy added main.py"
APPLICATION_ID: hidden
CLIENT_SECRET: hidden
Attempting to get access token...

Error: Failed to acquire access token: {'error': 'invalid_grant',
'error_description': "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not
consented to use the application with ID 'hidden' named 'azure app for
api python'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user
and resource. Trace ID: hidden Correlation ID: hidden Timestamp:
2024-11-29 02:49:38Z", 'error_codes': [65001], 'timestamp':
'2024-11-29 02:49:38Z', 'trace_id': 'hidden', 'correlation_id':
'hidden', 'suberror': 'consent_required'}

Here is the full code
import os
import webbrowser
import msal
from dotenv import load_dotenv


MS_GRAPH_BASE_URL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0'


def get_access_token(application_id, client_secret, scopes):
    client = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id=application_id,
        client_credential=client_secret,
        authority='https://login.microsoftonline.com/(hidden-tenantID#usedhere)'


####


    )


    # Check if there is a refresh token stored
    refresh_token = None
    if os.path.exists('refresh_token.txt'):
        with open('refresh_token.txt', 'r') as file:
            refresh_token = file.read().strip()


    if refresh_token:
        # Try to acquire a new access token using the refresh token
        token_response = client.acquire_token_by_refresh_token(refresh_token, scopes=scopes)
    else:
        # No refresh token, proceed with the authorization code flow
        auth_request_url = client.get_authorization_request_url(scopes)
        webbrowser.open(auth_request_url)
        authorization_code = input('Enter the authorization code: ')


        if not authorization_code:
            raise ValueError("Authorization code is empty")


        token_response = client.acquire_token_by_authorization_code(
            code=authorization_code,
            scopes=scopes
        )


    if 'access_token' in token_response:
        # Store the refresh token securely
        if 'refresh_token' in token_response:
            with open('refresh_token.txt', 'w') as file:
                file.write(token_response['refresh_token'])


        return token_response['access_token']
    else:
        raise Exception('Failed to acquire access token: ' + str(token_response))




def main():
    load_dotenv()
   
    # Check if the environment variables are loaded correctly
    APPLICATION_ID = os.getenv('APPLICATION_ID')
    CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv('CLIENT_SECRET')
    print(f"APPLICATION_ID: {APPLICATION_ID}")  # Debug: Check if environment variable loaded correctly
    print(f"CLIENT_SECRET: {CLIENT_SECRET}")  # Debug: Check if environment variable loaded correctly
   
    SCOPES = ['User.Read', 'Mail.ReadWrite', 'Mail.Send']
# add print for scopes
    try:
        print("Attempting to get access token...")  # Debug
        access_token = get_access_token(application_id=APPLICATION_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, scopes=SCOPES)
        print(f"Access Token: {access_token}")  # Debug to show if token was retrieved
        headers = {
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + access_token
        }
        print(f"Headers: {headers}")  # Debug to show headers
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')
   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()




other steps i took
I tried redoing the whole thing and the initial setup which is creating a python venv and azure app registration for client secret and application id variables in that venv using my moms (bosses) azure account
from my moms account from azure which could be irrelevant as im still receiving the same error and not familiar with azure were (and which required me to activate my p2 subscription pls let me know if this is necessary)  were going into roles and admins> admin units and created an admin unit and also added myself as a user administrator inside that admin unit under that created admin user> roles and administrators> user administrator, i also tried adding API permissions like mail.readwrite and , male.send but msgraph not listed as available option where i looked and both of these other steps of which are only attempts at resolving and not sure are even irrelevant to my code / its error
.........................

Can you paste the screenshot of API permission blade of the application

I ended up finding ms graph popped up for some reason another time on the permissions so i was able to add the mail.readwrite and mail.send permissions i edidted my post with my follow up attempts if youd like to check them out im still getting some errors from azure side of things most likely

its says granted for all 3 permissions (although not sure if this matters or not it says admin consent required yes for 2 no for 1) im not sure that matters given the next steps i took

Thank you for the help i dont remember now but i got it all good i mistyped the redirect url for one but also took many other admin steps in total so idk which of those helped too

The error AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application occurs because the Azure AD administrator has not granted the necessary permissions for your app to access Microsoft Graph API on behalf of a user.
Solution:

Grant Admin Consent:

Have your administrator (your mom) log in to the Azure portal.
Go to Azure Active Directory > Enterprise applications > Your app.
Under Permissions, click Grant admin consent for [Your Organization Name].


Use the Correct Authority URL:
For work accounts, use the following authority URL:
authority = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/'




Replace {tenant_id} with your organization's Azure AD tenant ID.

Check API Permissions:


Ensure that your app has the necessary Microsoft Graph permissions
like Mail.ReadWrite and Mail.Send under API permissions.
If the permissions are missing, add them and grant admin consent.

Once admin consent is granted, your app should be able to acquire an access token without this error.

Thank you for the information ive followed up by editing my original post on my new attempts if youd like to check them out (too long to post in a comment included errors)
